# I have a domain but I just want to 301 to my behance page

Tags: dns, hosting, redirect

I have a domain and I pay $10/monthly to site5 host my portfolio. But now, I just need a Behance page. Is there any way to redirect my domain to behance, without having a host service?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you can set up a 301 redirect directly from the domain name's control panel no?